Relationship between "Project/Module SDK" and min/compile/targetSDK?
in Intellij/IDEA, what should I select on my project/module properties' SDK field?
the minSdk value? the targetSDK value? or the compileSDK value?
I'm split between the min and compile ones. Note that I have different values for all properties on most projects.
